# Sharepoint 2007 WebPart connection not available

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have problem with connection between 2 webParts in Sharepoint 2007. This option is not visible under my webPart menu.

I have enabled connections in central administration. I have enabled Allow Connection in both webParts I want to connect.

What I need to do to enable it?

Comment: I have found that running site under IE* compability mode shows Connections in Drop-Down menu, but clicking this option does nothing. Question: How to enable it on newer browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you use IE 7 or IE 8 for SharePoint 2007. SharePoint 2007 has a known browser compatibility issue in Chrome, Firefox including the problem you are facing. Microsoft resolved this issue in SharePoint 2010/2013 but for SharePoint 2007 you should use IE 8.